# HorizontalScrollView fill entire screen with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating layout with `ScrollView` that have `HorizontalScrollView` and some `EditText`.. It looks like the image below..

[image]

So far my code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
    >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/mainHorizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic1"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    ></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic2"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    ></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic3"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    ></ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
            />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewDetail"
            />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My code above make the `ScrollView` not working..
Is there any way to make the `HorizontalScrollView` fill the entire screen while some of the `TextView` is still visible so the user know its scrollable?

Comment: the linear layout is inside a vertical `ScrollView` so the height won't be match_parent, but wrap_content, the horizontal scroll view will also have wrap content as height. If you want to let the user know that he can scroll you can use the fade effect and/or the scroll bar. for the fade effect you can use `android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"`(or something like this), you can also set the fading edge size

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my code. It worked for me.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/casts_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="345dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="for demo purpose"
                        android:textSize="50dp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="345dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="for demo purpose"
                        android:textSize="50dp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="345dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="for demo purpose"
                        android:textSize="50dp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```